# Javascript RegEx - invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw the other posts but none of them help me ...

So, i tried to match url in a string in javascript with regex it works perfectly on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gM8tC2/2) but fails in javascript.

```js
var matches = feed.content.match(
    '/((http|https|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\%]+\/?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+\/?)*(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\%\+\=\&\:]*)*)/ig'
    );
```

And firebug returns me

```
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier
```

Please can you help me ?

Comment: Regexes should not have quotes around them.

Comment: You're also escaping way more characters than you need to, making it difficult to read.

Comment: Perhaps use a regexp object and make this easier on yourself as well. `var re = new RegExp('((https?|ftp)://([\\w%.-]+/?)([\\w.-]+/?)*(\\?[\\w%.+=&:-]*)*)', 'gi')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081462/javascript-regex-invalid-quantifier#comment39023480_25081462), you should remove the single quotes enclosing the regex. As well as that, I would propose making a few changes to the expression itself:

```
((https?|ftp):\/\/([\w.%-]+\/?)([\w.-]+\/?)*(\?[\w.%+=&:-]*)*)
```

The `?` after the `s`means that it is optional, so http and https will both match. `\w` is the word character class, so that covers `A-Za-z0-9_` much more concisely. There's no need to escape all the symbols but a useful trick is to put the `-` at the end of the character class, so that it isn't interpreted as a range between two characters. The `{1}` isn't necessary as that's the default behaviour.

[updated on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gM8tC2/4)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the regex as a string - just get rid of the outer quotes.

```
var matches = feed.content.match(
    /((http|https|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\%]+\/?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+\/?)*(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\%\+\=\&\:]*)*)/ig
    );
```